# Spring Cloud Gateway Failed to start: Unable to find GatewayFilterFactory with name <blank>

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-gateway

Spring Cloud Gateway failed to start, and gives the following exception:

```
service-gateway      | 2020-01-02 13:44:55.910  INFO 22 --- [           main] c.n.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator     : InstanceInfoReplicator onDemand update allowed rate per min is 4
service-gateway      | 2020-01-02 13:44:55.915  INFO 22 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Discovery Client initialized at timestamp 1577943895914 with initial instances count: 11
service-gateway      | 2020-01-02 13:44:55.916  INFO 22 --- [           main] o.s.c.n.e.s.EurekaServiceRegistry        : Registering application SERVICE-GATEWAY with eureka with status UP
service-gateway      | 2020-01-02 13:44:55.917  INFO 22 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Saw local status change event StatusChangeEvent [timestamp=1577943895917, current=UP, previous=STARTING]
service-gateway      | 2020-01-02 13:44:55.923  INFO 22 --- [nfoReplicator-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_SERVICE-GATEWAY/a5881e80ffd5:service-gateway:1790: registering service...
service-gateway      | 2020-01-02 13:44:55.991  INFO 22 --- [nfoReplicator-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_SERVICE-GATEWAY/a5881e80ffd5:service-gateway:1790 - registration status: 204
service-gateway      | 2020-01-02 13:44:56.051  WARN 22 --- [           main] onfigReactiveWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'eurekaAutoServiceRegistration'; nested exception is reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to find GatewayFilterFactory with name 
service-gateway      | 2020-01-02 13:44:56.083  INFO 22 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Shutting down DiscoveryClient ...
service-gateway      | 2020-01-02 13:44:59.085  INFO 22 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Unregistering ...
service-gateway      | 2020-01-02 13:44:59.093  INFO 22 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_SERVICE-GATEWAY/a5881e80ffd5:service-gateway:1790 - deregister  status: 200
service-gateway      | 2020-01-02 13:44:59.104  INFO 22 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Completed shut down of DiscoveryClient
```

Answer (score 0):

In spring cloud gateway code that used to create filter it says:

```
GatewayFilterFactory factory = this.gatewayFilterFactories.get(definition.getName());
                    if (factory == null) {
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unable to find GatewayFilterFactory with name " + definition.getName());
                    }
```

so if it failed to to create the gatewayFilterFactory, the exception should gives a message:

"Unable to find GatewayFilterFactory with name `<some name>`", But there is no such thing in my log, just "Unable to find GatewayFilterFactory with name ". After 2 days of research and I finally found, there is an error in my config file:

```
        - id:  api_assets
          uri: lb://BACKEND
          predicates:
            - Path=/api/assets/**
          filters:
            - name: AuditFilter
            -
```

A LIST OF FILTER NAMES WITH A BLANK ONE